# Change the UINavigation toolbar position in iOS7?

Tags: ios6, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uitoolbar, uiviewanimation

Does anyone know how to change the position of the toolbar in iOS7?  I have a text field on my tool bar that needs to be viewable when the keyboard appears during editing.

In iOS6 i just animated the toolbar frame and changed the toolbar's position but it doesn't seem to work in iOS7.  Is there a way to to do this in iOS7?

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{   
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                           delay:0.0
                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                      animations:^{
                           [self.navigationController.toolbar 
                                  setFrame:
                             CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 172, 320, 44)];
                      }
                      completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I added another button to the animation and then tried changing the toolbar frame in the completion block instead and it worked! The other button is just there to resignFirstResponder by pressing outside the keyboard.  I have no idea why it worked this way but I am not complaining:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{   
    self.done = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 0)];
    self.done.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
    [self.done  addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.done];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         [self.done setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - 172 + 20)];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [self.navigationController.toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 172 + 20, 320, 44)];
                     }
     ];
}
```

Another thing I noticed is that I couldn't change the translucent property of my tool bar. When I tried to implement:

```
self.navigationController.toolbar.translucent = YES;
```

or when I tried to implement:

```
self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

It caused the animation completion block code to not work. I'm not sure if this is a bug or what?